# How to do a bar plot data continuously in Matplotlib (in sequence)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Ok, the problem is quite simple, I guess. What I'm trying to do is a bar plot where the data is plotted in sequence, ignoring if the current value is smaller than the previous one. For example, the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for index in range(len(x)): 
    plt.bar(x[index], y[index])
```

returns me this plot:

[image]

But if I add a new value to x and y (the new x value being smaller than the previous value), like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200]

for index in range(len(x)): 
    plt.bar(x[index], y[index])
```

the plot goes like this:

[image]

So, *finally*, how can I plot this new 2 value after 10 instead of going back right to the value previously plotted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot the against the range value and adjust the ticks label:

```
plt.bar(range(len(x)), y)
plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)
```

Output:

[image]